# How to connect to squid proxy docker container to use ftp-proxy?

Tags: docker, ftp, squid

I am using squid proxy server in docker container to use ftp-proxy. As following. https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/squid/
My modified docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic-20190612

ENV SQUID_VERSION=3.5.27 \
    SQUID_CACHE_DIR=/var/spool/squid \
    SQUID_LOG_DIR=/var/log/squid \
    SQUID_USER=proxy

RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y squid=${SQUID_VERSION}* \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV http_proxy=test.rebex.net \
    https_proxy=test.rebex.net \
    ftp_proxy=test.rebex.net:21

COPY entrypoint.sh /sbin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /sbin/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 3128/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Running the docker container with command:

```
docker run --name squid  \                                                                                                   
  --publish 3128:3128 \
  squid-proxy
```

I want to connect to the ftp `test.rebex.net` with my filezilla through the running docker. When I try to connect my filezilla ftp client to localhost:3128, the connection fails. How do I connect to the ftp server through squid ftp-proxy in docker?

Comment: You are mixing up proxy and final destination. The proxy settings in environment and possible in filezilla need to be set to the proxy (squid) while the final destination in filezilla need to be given as test.rebex.net. You are currently doing it exactly the other way.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am sorry it's still a bit unclear. What should I use as `ENV ftp_proxy` in squid docker container which will run on localhost and what should my destination address be in filezilla

Comment: The proxy setting in filezilla should reflect the proxy you use (port 3128 in the docker). The destination should reflect the final destination (test.rebex.net).